# stored Procedure returning issues

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

We have a stored procedure `spLocal_CmnUI_BMGetLatestBiasRecords`.
When we execute the stored procedure manually using `Declare statement` then it returns correctly. However, when we execute the stored procedure by using `Exec stored procedure` it returns invalid results.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Unpleasant news, of course. But would you be so kind to provide more information about this issue? Stored procedure text,how you execute it and why you think the results are invalid

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Show us some code, and how you execute the procedure. (Formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Microsoft Sql server - 2016

Comment: Results - Invalid means ( one column value swapped to other column )

Comment: When we checked the data in the tables are correct while displaying the results by executing the stored procedure the results got swapped